# How to list all files in a folder that start with a number?

Tags: c#, file, select

I have a folder with files in it.
This files are:

```
file1.txt
opera.exe
12_pro.bin
15th edition.txt
myFile.txt
```

Now, I need a code to get just the files that start wit a number

So, just these two:

```
12_pro.bin
15th edition.txt
```

I have this:

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (var path in Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(path); // full path
        Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)); // file name
    }
Console.ReadLine();
```

Now, i need something like this:
in the for loop, i need to check the name of the file, for the 1st letter:
something like: if the 1st letter is a number, then Write Line.

Comment: Surely you have everything there that you need - you know how to extract the filename - now you just check the first character of that name. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ and `Char.IsDigit`:

```
var numberFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).Where(f => Char.IsDigit(f[0]));

foreach(string fn in numberFiles)
    Console.WriteLine(fn);
```

Comment: ty bro, this helps a lot

Comment: @Stefan: you're welcome. Remember to accept an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the first character of your file name is numeric or not.

```
string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
int output;
bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(name[0].ToString(), out output);
if(isNumeric)
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple `Regex` to filter files starting with a number.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath)
                     .Where(x=> Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(x), @"^\d"));
```

Comment: I think that this case is a little to simple to involve regular expressions.